# Related $query->with but "pick properties as"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.13.

I am trying to fetch all Extensions but with certain extra properties based on their relations.

My goal is to get data like this, I am trying to get the `latest_comment_date`, `thumbs_count`, and `thumbs_yes_count`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Pull Refresh",
        "created_at": "2017-11-10 06:04:44",
        "updated_at": "2017-11-10 06:04:44",
        "latest_comment_date": "2017-11-10 05:46:25",
        "thumbs_count": 10,
        "thumbs_yes_count": 2
    }
]
```

I tried this:

```
        return Extension::with([
            'comments' => function($query) { // rename to 'latest_comment_date'
                $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1);
            },
            'thumbs' => function($query) { // rename to 'thumbs_count'
                $query->count();
            },
            'thumbs' => function($query) { // rename to 'thumbs_yes_count'
                $query->where('like', '=', true)->count();
            }
        ])->get();
```

This gives me data like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Pull Refresh",
        "created_at": "2017-11-10 06:04:44",
        "updated_at": "2017-11-10 06:04:44",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "body": "heck ya baby",
                "displayname_id": 2,
                "extension_id": 3,
                "created_at": "2017-11-10 18:31:31",
                "updated_at": "2017-11-10 18:31:31"
            }
        ],
        "thumbs": []
    }
]
```

May you please help me to "pick as" stuff as I showed at top most?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For counting you should use `withCount` like so:

```
return Extension::withCount(
                'thumbs', 
                'thumbs as thumbs_yes_count' => function($query) {
                   $query->where('like', '=', true);
               })->get();
```

Reference: [Counting related models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

And for taking latest comment, you should create extra relationship like so:

```
public function latestComment()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Comment::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

so the whole code would look like this:

```
return Extension::with('latestComment')->withCount(
                'thumbs', 
                'thumbs as thumbs_yes_count' => function($query) {
                   $query->where('like', '=', true);
               })->get();
```

Comment: Wow! So fast a reply, thank you sir! So spectacular Laravel is amazing. Thanks for dealing with my newbie questions that I am not able to find because I'm not a good searcher. Thanks very much! For the `latestComment` though, it's returning the whole latest comment, is it possible to "pick" the "created_at" field out of there, as we did with `thumbs_yes_count`?

Comment: @Blagoh Rather not, You can limit number of fields but it won't make having such flat structure. However depending on your needs you might want to use some transformers if you want to put those data into json to return only those data you really need

Comment: Thanks sir may you please guide me to some info about transformers, whenever you have time, no rush. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks!! I really appreciate your help!